# Override vim command for yank

Tags: vim

The shortcut Y, for some reason, does not operate the way D and C
do. Instead of yanking from the current position to the end of the
line, Y yanks the whole line. Y does the same thing as yy.

Is it possible to override this functionality ?
I want Y to acts as y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. Pertaining to your question, `:help Y` offers this:

> If you like "Y" to work from the cursor to the end of line (which is more logical, but not Vi-compatible) use `:map Y y$`.

Answer (score 4):

Use a map in Normal mode:

```
:nnoremap Y y$
```